# Calling the endpoint with the RequestSizeLimit attribute using HttpClient throws an error

Tags: c#, .net, http, dotnet-httpclient

There is a simple test endpoint.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [RequestSizeLimit(1024 * 1024 * 5)]
    public IActionResult Test(IFormFile fileContent)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

File size is 10 Mb.

When using Swagger, it returns the following (as I expect).

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-3df32281eb3d9830c73a5e455d700666-149c2c80738d0489-00",
  "errors": {
    "": [
      "Failed to read the request form. Request body too large. The max request body size is 5242880 bytes."
    ]
  }
}
```

When using HttpClient

```
  using var client = new HttpClient();
  using var httpContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
  using var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\333.pdf"));
  httpContent.Add(fileContent, "fileContent", "222.pdf");
  using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri("https://localhost:7235/test"));
    
  request.Content = httpContent;

  using var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
  var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Or like following:

```
using var client = new HttpClient();
using var httpContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

using var stream = File.OpenRead("D:\\333.pdf");

using var fileContent = new StreamContent(stream);
httpContent.Add(fileContent, "fileContent", "222.pdf");
using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri("https://localhost:7235/test"));
        
request.Content = httpContent;

using var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

It throw an exception:

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Error while copying content to a stream.'

Inner Exceptions:
IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

**StackTrace**

at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.<g__WaitAsync|56_0>d.MoveNext()
at System.Net.Http.MultipartContent.d__23.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.<g__WaitAsync|56_0>d.MoveNext()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.d__70.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.d__64.MoveNext()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.d__64.MoveNext()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.d__84.MoveNext()
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.d__4.MoveNext()
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<g__Core|83_0>d.MoveNext()
at ConsoleApp2.Program.d__0.MoveNext() in D:\Local Projects\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\Program.cs:line 44

[image]

But if I set limit size less than 1 Mb

```
RequestSizeLimit(1024 * 500)
```

And send file till 1 Mb and grater limit its work fine and return 400 as I expecting.

The same behavior when I tried to make a call using python (exception another).

How to make a call and receive correct response?

Comment: I don't know, but that looks like an inefficient way of passing a large file. You should probably do `File.OpenRead` and pass the resulting stream to a `StreamContent`. You should also dispose the request and response objects with `using`, and use a static `HttpClient` object rather than creating one every time.

Comment: What's the size of the `333.pdf` file?

Comment: @Charlieface 
1) "and use a static HttpClient object rather than creating one every time" it's simple console app for test. 
2) File.OpenRead - the same result

Comment: @WBuck added to description (10 mb)

Comment: When you send a file whose size is smaller than `5MB` what happens?

Comment: I never said you wouldn't have the same result. Was just saying recommended practice, to make your app more efficient and robust. The actual issue I don't know the answer to.

Comment: @WBuck if file size less than limit it's work fine. I found it's work fine if limit less than 1 mb and file also. Limit = 500kb file size 900 kb => return 400. if Limit 500kb file size > 1 mb => exception.... wtf

Comment: @РомаМатковский do you get any exceptions server-side? Otherwise I would suggest to try change the buffer size of StreamContent and see if that has any impact. It seems like some edge case related to 5MB size.

Comment: @IhorKorotenko idk because if i set limit to 100 mb and send 99 it's work fine. Seams the issue related to the attribute

Comment: @IhorKorotenko with postman and swagger works fine.... but .net also python throw an error